# Подсветка asm синтаксиса

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ассемблер

Я скачал и установил расширение [`AsmHighlighter`](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6b069ed9-963a-430d-be66-7dace0f1f1c2) для `Visual Studio 2015`, в графе расширений оно отображается, однако никакой подсветки `asm` синтаксиса нет. Почему так?

Comment: Думаю, вам стоит обратиться к авторам расширения.

Comment: @VladD Просто в описании написано `"It looks like there may be some destructive interaction with other extensions like Visual Assist."`. Может быть с этим связано?

Comment: Хотя у меня вроде бы только стандартные стоят

Comment: А что там думать? Почитайте, не описана ли ваша проблема в их документации, и сообщайте им баг.

Comment: @VladD Хорошо, так и сделаю

Comment: Там у них есть «Вопросы и ответы», гляньте

Answer (score 1):

Данное расширение AsmHighlighter работает только для файлов с расширением .asm (в том числе и в VS 2015+)
С ассемблерными вставками _asm оно не работает.